# How use constant in type definition in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY DAIS2 AS
G_TIMLIGA CONSTANT NUMBER:=20;
PROCEDURE GENZAPAS
AS
TYPE MYOWNARRAY IS VARRAY(G_TIMLIGA) OF KURZ%ROWTYPE;
```

I'm creating package and i need have group of constants like     G_TIMLIGA and use its in many procedures and functions and i don't want to change all defenitions. Is some way to do this?

Comment: You are showing a constant being declared.  What is the problem?

Comment: i need use this constant in declaration of type. Look at bottom line of my code TYPE MYOWNARRAY IS VARRAY(G_TIMLIGA) OF KURZ%ROWTYPE;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find an explicit interdiction in the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDEIJHD), but, as I know, you have to use number in type declaration and you can't use previously defined constant. If you need array type with length defined by a constant, try to use another collection types (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005). But in this case you need write some additional code to control size, may be even create your own API for working with this structure.

Comment: Thanx. I will use something else.